# getting GLIBC_2.14 Error end of directadmin installation

Tags: directadmin

i have a clean centos 6.5 installed.

i got my licence for directadmin ready.

i started installation everything went fine but the end of the installation that it gives us the password of directadmin panel login.

but it says:

```
Type: /sbin/service httpd restart
Stopping crond:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting crond:                                            [  OK  ]
./directadmin: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./directadmin)
./directadmin: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./directadmin)

System Security Tips:
  http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=247


*********************************
*
* Cannot find /usr/local/directadmin/conf/directadmin.conf
* Please see this guide:
* http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=267
*
*********************************`
```

i have also used `yum update` to update the os but nothing...

i installed directadmin before, thing like this have not happend to me since now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that you have wrong OS set in the license file in our system. Please check your OS version with following command.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

And try to update build on your server.

```
/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/build update_da
```

Thanks